# Python Unit Test Mock for Pandas max variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a function which throws an exception when the max of column A is equal to a number (say 5). I want to unittest this function to check if it throws the Exception.

main.py

```
import pandas as pd

class DuplicateRunError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def pd_max(df1):
    max_a = df1['A'].max()
    if max_a == 5:
        raise DuplicateRunError("Max Value for A reached")
    else:
        return "All Good"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(pd_max(pd.read_csv("file1.csv")))
```

I created a unittest for this function like below.

main_test.py

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import pandas as pd

class TestRaiseException(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('df1["A"].max()')
    def test_pd_max(self, mock_max_a):
        mock_max_a.return_value = 5
        with self.assertRaises(DuplicateRunError):
            pd_max(pd.read_csv("file1.csv"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'df1["A"]'`
I want to mock the value of df1["A"].max()

What is missing here?
What is the best way to set the value for df1["A"].max()
I think I could get it working if i mock the dataframe object by passing a dict and then passing it to the function. But I want to know if there is way to directly set the value as 5 for df1["A"].max()

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this. Since `df` is an input to your function, you can actually mock the specific functionality you need

```
class TestRaiseException(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('pandas.DataFrame')
    def test_pd_max(self, mock_df):
        mock_df.max.return_value = 5

        with self.assertRaises(DuplicateRunError):
            pd_max(mock_df)
```

Another similar idea is to use `MagicMock` directly on the specific `max` method. This will keep the behavior for everything else. Using `@mock.patch` will mock other things beyond `.max` scope

```
class TestRaiseException(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_pd_max(self):
        actual_df = pd.read_csv(...)
        actual_df.max = MagicMock(return_value=5)

        with self.assertRaises(DuplicateRunError):
            pd_max(actual_df)
```

You can also encapsulate the specific call/logic into your own method and mock *that*. This is safer of side-effects

```
def pd_max(df1):
    max_a = self.get_max_val(df1)
    if max_a == 5:
        raise DuplicateRunError("Max Value for A reached")
    else:
        return "All Good"

def get_max_val(df1):
    return df1['A'].max()
```

---

```
class TestRaiseException(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('path.to.call.YourClass.get_max_val')
    def test_pd_max(self, mocked_method):
        mocked_method.return_value = 5

        with self.assertRaises(DuplicateRunError):
            pd_max(some_other_df) # you can pass an actual df in here
```

The first and second methods are OK if you don't rely on other `.max()` calls. However, it is hard to future-proof what other engineers might do with the code. E.g., if someone else adds functionalities relying on `.max()` throughout the method in the future, your test might be impacted in an unexpected way.

The last method encapsulates and focuses the mock only on your own method, keeping the `pd.DataFrame` real.

Comment: I tried both the first and second method but getting error as `AssertionError: DuplicateRunError not raised`

Comment: @AshokKS Works on my end. You're probably missing something

Comment: I even tried printing the value of max_a in main.py and it prints as `<MagicMock name='DataFrame.__getitem__().max()' id='5132435616'>` Ideally it should have printed the value 5 right? I didn't change anything other than what you have suggested.